# File to import not found or unreadable: singularitygs | Using Prepros

Tags: sass

I have installed singularity with bower, and am using prepros as a compiler.

Attempting to compile my .scss file returns the following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: singularitygs
```

At the top of my styles.scss file:

```
@import "compass/reset";
@import "singularitygs";
```

config.rb:

```
require 'singularitygs'

relative_assets = true
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
```

Additional info (that might be relevant): I am only 'watching' my public folder with Prepros, so config.rb file is at the root of that folder.

Anyone know what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now got this working with the following steps:

► Install Ruby gems on my system, and installed singularity
   using gems on the command line with:

`gems install singularity`

► Set Prepros to use system Ruby Installation (as opposed to built-in version) by going to *Prepros Options -> Advanced Options -> Use Custom Ruby*. (just enter 'ruby' if it's already in your path)

► Import compass, then singularity and breakpoint (the latter needed for responsive grids) in .scss file using:

```
@import "compass";
@import "singularitygs";
@import "breakpoint";
```

► Add config.rb file in project root and include the line:

```
require 'singularitygs'
```

Now it's all working sweet!

Comment: What operating system are you using? I'm using Mac, and my Prepros 5.2.0 doesn't have the options mentioned.

Comment: I using Windows 7, and it looks like I'm still on version 4.2